# Itterate through an array yields different results

Tags: javascript

I have an array list: `["April", "May", "June", "July"]`

Why is it that `if(arr[i] === "June")`, `result` will display "Found month", but `if(arr[i] === "April")` or `if(arr[i] === "May")`, it will display "Didn't find month"?

How can I revise the code, so that `result` will display `Found month` for `April` and `May`?

```
function holidays(arr) {
    let result = ''
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
        if(arr[i] === "June"){
            result = "Found month"
        } else {result = "Didn't find month"}
    } return result
  } 
  
  const months = ["April", "May", "June"];
  console.log(holidays(months));
```

Comment: Once you have a match you should exit the loop immediately otherwise the next iteration will destroy the previous result.

Comment: Better yet, consider using `some` or `find` depending on what you are trying to accomplish here.

Comment: How you format code matters, especially in terms of how readable it is and how easily you can spot errors when reviewing the code. I'd recommend that you use some kind of code formatter, e.g. prettier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to omit the `not found` assignment, because, you can not know in the first loop, if the right month appears in the next loop.

So move this to the end and exit early on found, because you need not to iterate the rest of the array.

```js
function holidays(arr) {
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (arr[i] === "June") {
            return "Found month";
        }
    }
    return "Didn't find month";
}

const months = ["April", "May", "June"];

console.log(holidays(months));
```

A shorte approach utilize [`Array#includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes).

```js
function holidays(arr) {
    return arr.includes("June")
        ? "Found month"
        : "Didn't find month";
}

const months = ["April", "May", "June"];

console.log(holidays(months));
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to break from the array so that the new result does not override the old result.

```js
function holidays(arr) {
  let result = ''
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i] === "May") {
      result = "Found month"
      break
    } else {
      result = "Didn't find month"
    }
  }
  return result
}

const months = ["April", "May", "June"];
console.log(holidays(months));
```

MDN reference for `break`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/break

But, if you need to check if an array includes something, you should use `Array.includes`:

```js
function holidays(arr) {
  return (arr.includes("May") ? "Found": "Not found")
}

const months = ["April", "May", "June"];
console.log(holidays(months));
```

MDN reference for `Array.prototype.includes`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes

Also, in the above example for `Array.includes`, I used something called ternary operators: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator